# How to execute dependency's bower postinstall?

Tags: git, bower

I am writing a git repo UI-Components that has its own Bower dependencies. In this repo there are `/src` and `/dist` directories. I am only pushing the `/src` directory to git, and am using gulp to generate the `/dist` directory so that the files in `/dist` can be included in whatever project is using UI-Components. I have a script in `.bowerrc` as follows:

```
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "gulp prep-dependency"
    }
```

`gulp prep-dependency` is a gulp task specified in my gulpfile. When I run `bower install` from the root directory, which contains `/src` and `.bowerrc` everything works as expected and the `postinstall` command is executed, which generates the `/dist` directory. Great.

Now, I want to be able to do the same thing from another project, let's call it ParentProject, which has UI-Components as a dependency.

I expect that when I am in the root directory of ParentProject and I run `bower install`, all of the bower dependencies included in ParentProject's `bower.json` will be installed. Good news, they are installed. Yay! Bad news, that `postinstall` command from UI-Components never gets executed, so there is never a `/dist` directory, which I need.

If `bower install` runs recursively through all of the dependencies, how come this postinstall is not getting picked up? Is it because the `.bowerrc` file from UI-Components is not getting pushed to git so ParentProject isn't even aware that there is a `postinstall`? I am not explicitly ignoring it in my `.gitignore` file. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Bower packages intended to contain ready-to-use (compiled) files.
When you run `bower install` in your ParentProject bower [will not use](https://bower.io/docs/config/#hooks) `.bowerrc` in dependencies in any matter:

> These hooks are not intended to provide a post-installation build step for component authors. As such, the configuration for these hooks is provided in the .bowerrc file in the parent project’s directory.

So you should either change the way you distribute UI-components (i.e.  push dist version / create separate repos for sources and bower components) or add custom build logic in your ParentProject